# Delay in loading Flutterflow custom widget

Tags: custom-action, flutterflow, custom-widgets

I have a project in flutterflow. I have used a package named 'syncfusion_flutter_gauges' from pub.dev for showing a speedometer. Used a custom widget for defining the package. Custom action for the same is defined on page-load. The speedometer should work with maximum value as the value from previous API response, and minimum value as zero. The pointer should move according to the value entered by the user in the TextField. Now the code is working as, only when the user enters the value in text field and enter key is pressed, the maximum value is shown in the speedometer, and the colour is not changing according to the value entered in the TextField.

I have defined the maximum amount variable and amount entered variable in the custom widget, and used  it in the custom widget properties, but still not working.